# Meaning of "hail a taxi, without having to watch them, without passenger, pass me by"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 24 and graduated cum laude from a respectable university with a double major in Mathematics and Computer Science. I was skilled enough to get a job in my industry before I even graduated from my university.
>
> I have traveled the world and speak 3 languages at an intermediate/advanced level, two of them European languages and one of them East Asian. I'm clean cut and articulate. I live in New York City with my wonderful Caucasian fiancé, who is also quite well educated and cultured.
>
> I could go on about how police mistreat me, the service that I get at restaurants is lackluster, and the very obvious difference in pay that I have compared to my white peers of comparable skillsets, but to be honest I'd really just like it if for one day, I could walk out of my apartment and **hail a taxi without having to watch them, without passenger, pass me by**.

I don’t really get the meaning of the last sentence “hail a taxi, without having to watch them, without passenger, pass me by”.

Comment: Can you tell us where this comes from?

Answer (score 2):

The author is saying that he is the victim of continuous, widespread discrimination despite his many achievements, all because of his appearance.  But of all the indignities he suffers, the most annoying is to not be able to *hail a taxi* outside his apartment, even when the taxis *don't have any passengers*.

There isn't enough context to say why the author is being discriminated against (although I can make an educated guess), but this kind of thing is not uncommon in the United States, even today.

The actual phrase "without passenger" is more *literary* or *poetic* than *grammatical*, and would be the equivalent of something like:

> a **with-no-passenger** taxi.

This is not a construction you would ordinarily use.  More typical examples would be:

> a taxi **without passengers**
>
> a taxi **without a single passenger**
>
> a taxi **without any passengers**

and possibly:

> a **passenger-less** taxi

Comment: Yes, and it should say: without passengers, without a passenger, or passenger-less.

Comment: @Lambie - I agree that those would be more common wording, but the quote here strikes me as more of a poetic phrasing than an ungrammatical one.

Comment: There is a rather literary use of "without" without an article even for words where you might expect one; especially if there is more than one item, eg "without hat or coat". Searching for "without [singular noun]" in the Corpus of Historical American English, most of the results are abstract nouns which don't take an article anyway (eg "without mercy"); but I notice "without warning", "without question", "without exception" in the top ten results: all of these are sort of abstract, but are usually treated as count nouns, not mass nouns.

Comment: @ColinFine Still and all, as they say, it's not a question,exception or warning, is it? It does not collocate with the rest of the discourse.